# Load CSV into Neo4j from local path without modifying config

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, load-csv

I need to load a CSV file into a Neo4j database using its .NET driver. I can use the following code to load the file.

```cs
var dataFile = "data.csv";
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));

using var session = driver.AsyncSession(x => x.WithDefaultAccessMode(AccessMode.Write));
await session.WriteTransactionAsync(async tx =>
{
    var result = await tx.RunAsync(
        $"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///{dataFile}' AS line " +
        "CREATE(:Artist { name: line.Name, year: toInteger(line.Year)})");
});
```

This requires that the file is located under the `C:/Users/user/.Neo4jDesktop/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-502b0f7e-04e2-4c24-9472-528775921429/import/` directory. If the `data.csv` file is located under a different directory, and I provide the fully quantifying path, I get the following error.

```cs
var dataFile = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.csv";
```

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/user/.Neo4jDesktop/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-502b0f7e-04e2-4c24-9472-528775921429/import/Users/user/Desktop/data.csv)'

I can fix this by commenting-out `dbms.directories.import=import` in Neo4j config. However, in my usecase, modifying config is not an option and writing to the `.Neo4jDesktop/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-***/import/` is not allowed.

Any thoughts on how I can load CSV from ***any*** directory without altering Neo4j configuration?

Comment: Importing a file outside "import" folder is a hard rule set by Neo4j. Please chase them about it thru https://neo4j.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the config file when importing a file outside "import" folder is a hard rule set by Neo4j. Please chase them about it thru

```
 https://neo4j.com/contact-us/
```

Why importing file to import folder is not allowed?